# Haxe: get path to the `std` library

Tags: haxe, haxelib

I need to get path to the `std` folder of `Haxe`.
On Linux system it can be `/usr/share/haxe/std`, on Windows -- `C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std\`.

There are `haxelib config`, `haxelib path` and `haxelib libpath` commands, but they point me to `/usr/local/lib/haxe/` folder.

How can I get this path in my script?

I tried these commands `haxelib config`, `haxelib path`, `haxelib libpath` but they help me only on Windows, because on Windows `std` and `lib` foldrs are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do this with Haxe:

ResolveStd.hx:

```
class ResolveStd {
    static macro function getStdPath() {
        var evalDir = haxe.macro.Context.resolvePath("eval");
        var stdDir = haxe.io.Path.directory(evalDir);
        return macro $v{stdDir};
    }
    public static function main() {
        Sys.println(getStdPath());
    }
}
```

and then

```
haxe --run ResolveStd.hx
```

will have output like

```
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std
```

(explanation: we're asking the compiler to resolve path of `eval`, which is one of the subdirectories in `std`, then going one level up)